# What use is Skill Beyond Your Years?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, feats, e6

In low-level D&D variant E6, you max out at level 6 and only gain feats every 5,000XP thereafter. There is a feat as follows:

> **Skill Beyond Your Years**
>    **Prerequisite:** Level 6
>   Pick a skill. Your max ranks rise from Level+3 to Level +5.

Is this feat of any actual use? You can't gain levels past 6 in E6, and therefore can't gain further skill points even if your max ranks goes up.

Comment: Discussion in the E6 thread, besides "use Open Minded or the various +2 to 2 skills feats", proposes giving one skill point per feat you give out post level 6. Meets general approval.  http://www.enworld.org/forum/general-rpg-discussion/206323-e6-game-inside-d-d-4.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a feat called [**Open Minded**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicFeats.htm#openMinded) in 3.5 that gives you five extra skill points, so it could be used together with this feat. It would stack with **Skill Focus** etc, and might help you meet the prereqs of some otherwise unavailable feat.

Comment: Since feats cost 5000 XP, and Open Minded gives 5 skill points, my GM has houseruled that you can buy skill points for 1000 XP each, making this option slightly more viable.

Comment: The feat could also be taken before allocating 6th-level skill points, so that you can spend your points accordingly to get up to 11 ranks in things. The main advantage is that this allows you to qualify for things that require 10 and 11 ranks (and quite a few nice things do).

Answer (score 8):

While it does not seem like much at first it opens up a bevy of options previously unavailable at level 6.

For example, the Cloak Dance Feat from Expanded Psionics Handbook requires 10 Ranks in Hide; the Deft Strike feat from Complete Adventurer requires 10 ranks in Spot; the Graft Flesh feats from Libris Mortis requires 10 ranks in heal.

While 11 ranks isn't quite enough to open up the next set of skill tricks Skills Beyond Your Years in Conjunction with the Favored feat from Cityscape enables you to have 12 ranks in a given skill, opening up even more options.

Elven Spell Lore (players handbook 2) - Knowledge (Arcana) 12 Ranks

Echoing Spell (secrets of xen'drik)- Spellcraft 12 Ranks

Music of Growth (eberon campaign setting) - Perform 12 Ranks

Quicken Utterance (tome of magic) - Truespeak 12 Ranks

Fell Conspiracy [inviolate link option] (exemplars of evil) - Knowledge Religion 12 Ranks

This has inspired me to make a guide dedicated to finding niche feats and options that require 10-12 ranks. Look for it on Giant in the Playground.

Comment: This doesn't appear to address that this question is in the context of E6?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No, I think the poster has a point: Skill Beyond Your Years increases your max ranks from 9 to 11, opening up certain feats. Technically the question asked "why increase max ranks when you can't gain any more skill points", but this answer gives some interesting uses for those extra skill points.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. Since you already have 20 rep, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie As Jonathan mentioned my post was entirely in the context of E6. I listed options for people who took the Skills beyond your years feat, an E6 specific feat.

Comment: Not being an E6 player, I wasn't sure! I understand better now what this is suggesting. Have a +1. :)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you're going for, you can only get skill focus once (and you can do that further down the line).  Plus, your DM will probably let you take the feat before allocating skill points so you can have the advantage of the highest rank in the game for that skill.